# Don't know how to translate dynamic strings with WP plugin Translatepress

Tags: wordpress, translation

I'm building a Wordpress site for a B&B and I want to make it multilingual (Italian and English), so I'm using Translatepress. My problem is that I don’t know how to translate the strings shown by the dynamic variables (those with the format like %d, 1%s, etc) whose content I have written in the backend of the site, using the plugin Hotel Booking by Motopress.

The issue is on the site but also in the emails sent by the plugin (which, for the rest, I have translated with the shortcode [trp_language language=”xx_xx”] [/trp_language]).

I thought that maybe I could fix this with some conditional PHP snippet like <?if (get_locale() == ‘en_GB’){instructions to replace the strings based on the current language}> or something along those lines, but my knowledge of PHP is basically zero, and I wouldn’t know how to code without breaking the site (also, this method wouldn't work for the e-mails, I'm afraid).

I checked out the page https://translatepress.com/translate-dynamic-strings-wordpress/ in the plugin developers' site but it doesn’t contain any solution unfortunately. For the php method, I've searched all over the Internet but without finding anything.

Thanks in advance for any help.